# Send SMTP Mail from BUSINESS gmail(like: abc@company.com) - PHP Mailer

Tags: smtp, gmail, phpmailer, google-workspace, mailer

As I am trying to send Email from Php mailer from My Business Gmail(example: Abc@domain.com) :

Have tried sending mail through Gmail from php mailer by generating **app password** from my personal Email id (Example: abc@gmail.com) And It is working.

Same thing I am trying to do from my business (G-suit for Business) Gmail But I am not able to see Option to generate App Password as I it is visible in basic Gmail Account. And without **app password** Gmail does not allow password to be in plain text. Please Help me on this if someone have faced this kind of Issue.

Answer (score 1):

As you've noticed, regular gmail and suite have differences. You have two options here:

- Enable the "less secure apps" option to allow regular `PLAIN` and `LOGIN` auth types.
- Use `XOAUTH2` authentication.

There is a long article about [using `XOAUTH2` for gmail in the PHPMailer wiki](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Using-Gmail-with-XOAUTH2). There are also [code examples](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/tree/master/examples).

The "less secure apps" option isn't really much less secure; credentials are in plain text (or lightly encoded), but the connection is protected by TLS.

There is more discussion of [gmail authentication in the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#gmail-oauth2-and-allow-less-secure-apps).